# What system configuration tools are used to start Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've been interested in programming for years, and I've been wondering how Windows 7 is started up in the first place. Then I found out about the system configuration tools stored in **"C:\Windows"** folder. One of the files is used to shut the computer down (i.e., **"shutdown.exe"** found in **"C:\Windows\System32"**), so I supposed that another is used to start it up, but I can't find it.

Just asking... Hack to learn.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can't run most executables before the system environment is available to execute them in, so while boot code is "executable" by definition, it is very differant from windows executables. Most of what you are asking about is taken care of by the boot-sectors bootstrap code.

Answer (score 2):

`shutdown.exe` isn't actually part of the shutdown process. At most, it is used to *request* a shutdown (e.g. across the network); just like the "Shutdown" button, it merely sends a message to the "smss.exe" process.

---

The Windows NT boot process is described in great detail in various articles:

- http://jdebp.eu./FGA/windows-nt-6-boot-process.html
- http://jdebp.eu./FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11341.the-windows-7-boot-process-sbsl.aspx

The rough outline is:

- bootloader (NTLDR or BOOTMGR/winload.exe)
- kernel (ntoskrnl.exe or ntkrnl*.exe)
- session manager subsystem (smss.exe)
- client-server runtime subsystem (csrss.exe)